# How to remove the Child in ActionScript3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, marquee

I added the child each and Every time,once the child  is added,when i add the next child the previous child is deleted this is my goal. am trying to remove the Child ,But Nothing Displayed in my screen.
here my coding

```
var tf:TextField = new TextField();
tf.text = chatData.message;<---------here i add the text dynamically
listChat.addChild(tf); // <----------------------------------here i added the child

var t:Timer = new Timer(150);
t.addEventListener(
TimerEvent.TIMER,
function(ev:TimerEvent): void
{
    tf.text = tf.text.substr(1) + tf.text.charAt(0);

}

);

t.start();
listChat.removeChild(tf);// <----------------------------------here i remove the child

 }
```

how can i remove the child? Anybody help me,Thanks in Advance!

Comment: listChat removes the text field on the same frame that it is added.  As well, I don't believe the logic within your timer will marquee the text as you expect.

Comment: ok How Can i remove the Child Sir?

Comment: Your code add adds then immediately removes the child, to which I believe you state: "But Nothing Displayed in my screen" means you don't see it because you just removed the child.

Comment: ya Correct. when i Send data (chatData.message),Each and every time its append sir.That's my problem,So i decided to remove Child.How Can i solve this problem

Comment: -1 for nonsensical question. You write "here i remove the child" then later "how can i remove the child?". You just removed it so what is your question?

Comment: Am trying to remove but i Cannot to remove it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i got Answer
here my Coding

```
var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
myFormat.size = 35;
var tf:TextField = new TextField();
tf.maxChars=100;
tf.text = chatData.message;
tf.defaultTextFormat=myFormat;
tf.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
tf.x = tf.y = 100;  
listChat.addChild(tf);
var t:Timer = new Timer(150);
t.addEventListener(
TimerEvent.TIMER,
function(ev:TimerEvent): void{
tf.text = tf.text.substr(1) + tf.text.charAt(0);    
}   
);
t.start();
if(listChat!=null)
for (var i:int = listChat.numChildren-2; i >= 0; i--)
{
listChat.removeChildAt (i);//here i remeve the Child
}

}
```